# Failure to invoke secure proxy service in WSO2 ESB from SOAP UI

Tags: apache, apache-axis, soapui, rampart, wso2-esb

I'm trying to call a secure proxy service in WSO2 ESB. I followed this great [tutorial](http://tryitnw.blogspot.com/2013/07/invoking-secured-esb-proxy-service.html).

But When I am sending a secured request from SOAP UI. Service goes into timeout and I get a error in the ESB Logs. I double checked every step of the tutorial. But I don't know why it is not working.

**Note:**

I'm using WSO2 ESB 4.8.1 and SOAP UI 5.0.0.

**My Proxy Service Code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="EchoProxy"
       transports="https,http"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="disable"
       startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <log level="full" separator="First Log"/>
         <log level="full" separator="Second Log"/>
         <send>
            <endpoint>
               <address uri="http://localhost:8280/services/echo"/>
            </endpoint>
         </send>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <log level="full"
              separator=Out Sequence Log"/>
         <property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
         <property name="ClientApiNonBlocking" scope="axis2" action="remove"/>
         <send/>
      </outSequence>
   </target>
   <parameter name="disableREST">true</parameter>
   <parameter name="ScenarioID">scenario5</parameter>
   <enableSec/>
   <policy key="conf:/repository/axis2/service-groups/EchoProxy/services/EchoProxy/policies/SigEncr"/>
   <description/>
</proxy>
```

**Error in logs:**

```
[2015-02-17 16:32:54,793] ERROR - ServerWorker Error processing POST request for : /services/EchoProxy.EchoProxyHttpsSoap11Endpoint
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Message is not signed
    at org.apache.rampart.handler.RampartReceiver.setFaultCodeAndThrowAxisFault(RampartReceiver.java:180)
    at org.apache.rampart.handler.RampartReceiver.invoke(RampartReceiver.java:99)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invokeHandler(Phase.java:340)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invoke(Phase.java:313)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.invoke(AxisEngine.java:261)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:167)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processEntityEnclosingRequest(ServerWorker.java:411)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:183)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: org.apache.rampart.RampartException: Message is not signed
    at org.apache.rampart.PolicyBasedResultsValidator.validateEncrSig(PolicyBasedResultsValidator.java:264)
    at org.apache.rampart.PolicyBasedResultsValidator.validate(PolicyBasedResultsValidator.java:151)
    at org.apache.rampart.RampartEngine.process(RampartEngine.java:470)
    at org.apache.rampart.handler.RampartReceiver.invoke(RampartReceiver.java:92)
    ... 10 more
[2015-02-17 16:33:54,690]  WARN - SourceHandler Connection time out after request is read: http-incoming-1
```

The Rest of information you can find in the above mentioned tutorial.

Comment: What is the rampart version you are running? similar issue has been reported for JIRA in BPS here https://wso2.org/jira/browse/BPS-456

Comment: I am just a newbie to this stuff. Can you please tell me how to check which rampart version i am running. I triedto Google it but couldn't find any answer.

Comment: Did you followed module engagement step for you proxy service? Log in to ESB management console and navigate to the List services -> Echo Proxy Service -> Module Engagement. There you will find the rampart version you are using easily.

Comment: Thanks for the help. This is the version that i found. rampart-1.61-wso2v12.

Comment: can you add the client SOAP request you sent?

Comment: Brother Somehow , i have solved this issue. When i again perform all the configurations, i was able to send the request to my service. But now i am facing this issue.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28582769/how-to-decrypt-recieving-message-from-wso2-secured-proxy-service-in-soap-ui-5-0